# Distinguish a UIButton by tag

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've got a game board (an 8x8 array). Now I want to implement drawing function, each cell in the board is a UIButton with separate tag (from 0 to 63). How to get through the buttons (button with separate tags) also being able to use setImage() function?

A piece of my code:

```
for i in 0..<8 {
    for j in 0..<8{
        if gameBoard[i,j].rawValue == 1 {
            cellButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"whitePiece.png"), for: UIControlState())
        } else if (gameBoard[i,j].rawValue == 2){
            cellButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"blackPiece.png"), for: UIControlState())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error with the current code? What type is `gameBoard`? What are you trying to do: chess board, checkers board, etc?

Comment: How do you store the buttons? Please include some more context, especially about the data structure you use to store references to your buttons.

Comment: @keithbhunter there is no error, right now the code is setting only one "first" button, because I don't know how to iterate over buttons (button with tags). Let's say I wanted to have something working like this: cellButton.tag.SetImage()

Comment: @b4rt please include more code. How do you define the data structure in which you store references to your buttons? In what scope is the definition with respect to where you want to change the images from?

Comment: @DávidPásztor - I've created a button within the Interface Builder Storyboard, than copy-pasted to have 64 buttons with different tags (0 to 63). After that I've created an action and outlet. The button reference is:@IBOutlet weak var cellButton: UIButton!
Does having a button with multiple tags means having multiple buttons (I have only one button reference)?

Comment: If you have 64buttons on a `Storyboard`, you need to connect all 64 to an outlet collection. However, with this huge number of buttons, you are better off using either a collection view or since this will be a game, an `SKTileMap` seems an even better choice.

Comment: How than to distinguish one specific button from an outlet collection?

Comment: Outlet collections don't give you a reliable ordering of your buttons. I've had this mess me up in the past. If you add your buttons to an outlet collection in a specific order it seems to put them the array in that order, but the order in the array can change at any time without warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't make sense. It looks like you have an instance variable cellButton, and you're trying to use it to somehow set the image on all 64 of your buttons. That can't possibly work. If you have tags on your buttons you could use something like this:

Say you define your tag numbers as being in the range 100 to 188, where the 10's digit is the row number and the 1s digit is the column number:

```
for i in 0..<8 {
    for j in 0..<8{
        //Create a tag number for this cell
        let tagNumber = 100 + i * 10 + j
        guard let aCellButton = view.viewWithTag(tagNumber) as? UIButton else {
          print("Error. Can't find button with tag \(tagNumber)")
          continue
        }
        if gameBoard[i,j].rawValue == 1 {
            aCellButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"whitePiece.png"), for: .normal)
        } else if (gameBoard[i,j].rawValue == 2){
            aCellButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"blackPiece.png"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As others have said, using tags is not ideal. You'd be much better off using a collection view or some other approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a subview via tag by using the [UIView viewWithTag](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622429-viewwithtag) method.

```
var tag = 0
for i in 0..<8 {
    for j in 0..<8{
         guard let buttonToSet = self.view.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIButton else{
               print("Couldn't find button")
               continue 
         }

        if gameBoard[i,j].rawValue == 1 {
            buttonToSet.setImage(UIImage(named:"whitePiece.png"), for: UIControlState())
        } else if (gameBoard[i,j].rawValue == 2){
            buttonToSet.setImage(UIImage(named:"blackPiece.png"), for: UIControlState())
        }

        tag = tag + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `i * j` for the tag number won't work. i=1,j=0 and i=0,j=1 will have the same tag. Also, you need to make sure you don't try to use tag 0, since all views default to a tag value of 0. See my code.

Comment: Thanks @DuncanC.  I caught that too when going back over it. A little out of it this morning.  :)

Comment: I know the feeling. :) Note that your updated code is still using tag value 0 for the i=0,j=0 case, which will likely fail (Since viewWithTag will return ANY subview with a 0 tag, even labels and other views that are not part of the button grid.)

Comment: True on the 0 tag.  I'm leaving it as is just because he said that he tagged his buttons from 0 to 63.

Comment: Ok, but using tag numbers 0-63 will **not** work, so continuing under that assumption is doomed. You can only fetch a view with tag 0 if **every** other view has a non-zero tag, which might not be possible since the system adds private subviews to your view hierarchy.